# std::mutex error with ndk r12b

Tags: android, c++, qt, c++11, android-ndk

Using C++ std::mutex on android-gcc with ndk r12b gives the following errors

`/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/c++14_warning.h:32: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the forthcoming ISO C++ 2014 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++1y or -std=gnu++1y compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the forthcoming \
  ^`

How can I get around this error ? 
I am writing this code in a Qt app for android device. Any flags I can use on my .pro file to get around this ?

Comment: It tells you in the error message: add `-std=c++1y` to the compiler options

Comment: I have `CONFIG += c++11` added to my .pro file. Still getting the error Is there some other flag I should add ?

Comment: Change `c++11` to `c++1y`

Comment: tried changing it to `c++1y` . Doesn't work. also tried `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -O1` But that doesn't work as well

Comment: See https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/81  (tl;dr: you may need to define `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS` as a workaround).

Comment: The `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS` bug was fixed in r12, so that shouldn't be the issue.

A trivial Android.mk example using gnustl_static and `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11` with `#include <mutex>` works for me, as does `-std=c++1y` and `#include <shared_mutex>`.

The toolchain looks to be okay here, so I'm guessing it's either the way you're passing the cppflags or an issue with qt's build system.

Comment: @RichardCritten . Thanks a lot for that suggestion. it works now